# The closure of the sum is contained in the sum of the closures?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X=(X,|\cdot|$) be a Banach space and let $A,B \subset X$. Then
$$ \overline{A+B} \subset \overline{A}+\overline{B}\:?$$
Where, $\overline{A+B}$, $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ denotes the closure of the sets $A+B$, $A$ and $B$, respectively.

I do not know if this is true. But I tried to prove it as follows:

Let $x \in \overline{A+B}$ then exist $(x_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}} \subset A+B$ such that $x_n \longrightarrow x$. In addition also, exists $(a_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}} \subset A$ and $(b_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}} \subset B$. So,
$$a_n+b_n=x_n \longrightarrow x.$$
Hence, exists $y \in A$ and $z \in B$ such that 
$$ a_n  \longrightarrow y \:\: \text{and} \:\: b_n \longrightarrow z.$$
Therefore, $y+z=x$ and $y+z \in \overline{A}+\overline{B}.$ Therefore, $ \overline{A+B} \subset \overline{A}+\overline{B}$.

I was in doubt if I can guarantee the existence of the elements $ y $ and $ z $, in $ A $ and $ B $, respectively.

Is that correct?

Comment: It is correct that you cannot guarantee the existence of $y$ and $z$.  For example $a_n=nx$, $b_n=-(n-1+\frac{1}{n})x$.

Comment: But, is the result true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is not true, even in finite-dimension.  Consider $X=\mathbb R^2$ with any norm you want (the topology is the important part, and they all give the same one).  Consider $A=\mathbb R\times\{0\}$, and $B=\{(x,\frac{1}{x}):x>0\}$.  It shouldn't be too hard to convince yourself that $A$ and $B$ are closed, and that 
$$A+B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:y>0\}$$
is not closed.  Thus $\overline{A+B}$ is not a subset of $A+B=\overline{A}+\overline B$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=\ell_2$. Let $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be the canonical $\ell_2$ basis. Let $A=\{e_n: 1<n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and let $B=\{-e_n+\frac{1}{n}e_1: 1<n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then $A,B$ are closed sets (they are norm discrete, each point of $A$  is a distance at least $\sqrt{2}$ to any other point of $A$, and similarly for $B$). Moreover, $0\notin A+B=\overline{A}+\overline{B}$. But $e_n+(-e_n+\frac{1}{n}e_1)\in A+B$, so $0\in \overline{A+B}$.